# CSS: select LI in multiple parent UL classes

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have defined two `<ul>` classes, **px_p** and **px_s**. Now I want to style all `<li>` elements that are contained within either `<ul class="px_p">` or `<ul class="px_s">` elements.
I had thought that `ul.px_p, ul.px_s li {}` would work, but no dice. I tried `ul.px_p li, ul.px_s li {}` as well. 
The issue is that the `<li>` styling is

```
ul.px_p, ul.px_s li {
  margin: 0.1em;
}
```

and .1em is being applied to the whole `<ul>` element, as well as the nested `<li>` elements. I just want the `<li>` elements, as the `<ul>` has a much larger bottom margin to graphically separate it from the following elements. The difference between **px_p** and **px_s** is _p is Primary, and has a bullet, while _s is secondary and has no bullet, it just indents more.

Comment: `ul.px_p li, ul.px_s li {}` should work as expected

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: @fabrizio-calderan Interesting. I tried that, and I saved the CSS, waited until the screen refreshed, then refreshed the web page, with no change in the presentation. So I assumed I had done something wrong. Refreshed the page a second time and still nothing. But now, after another save of the css file, and a refresh, all good. Is it really Monday? ;)\

Comment: @Gordon Remember to force a full refresh of your web page using `CTRL`+`F5` when working with CSS changes.  The browser will quite often cache the updates you have made

Comment: So I voted to close this question because the problem can no longer be reproduced.

Comment: @Gordon Also, imo `ul.px_p li, ul.px_s li` should probably really be `ul.px_p > li, ul.px_s > li`.  Otherwise your `li` style will apply to all `li` elements underneath the `ul` (even nested ones)

Comment: @Martin, thanks for that > hint. Selectors at this level of detail are new to me. Good stuff! As for the refresh, I had used the button (Safari, for what it's worth), I assume that is no different from a shortcut key?

Comment: @Gordon You're welcome.  `>` literally means a direct descendent.  Clicking the refresh button is not the same as a forced full refresh

Comment: @fabrizio-calderan Not sure I understand. It's not reproduced because it is fixed. @Martin 's `ul.px_p > li, ul.px_s > li` is really a useful answer, so it seems like having that as an accepted answer would be useful for others learning the nuances of selectors.

Comment: @Martin, do you want to formulate that response, both the CSS selector and the refresh info perhaps, as an answer I can then accept? I think both are super useful for us noobs. And enough people voted to reopen that I guess "us noobs" isn't just me. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The selector should be like this:

```
ul.px_p > li,
ul.px_s > li {
  ...
}
```

Using the `>` selector will only match `li` elements whose parent elements are `ul.px_p` or `ul.px_s`.

This is important, given that `ul.px_p li` will match *any* descendednt `li` element `ul.px_s`.  This will include nested elements which the style should not apply to.

As an side note, sometimes when working in browsers, a cached version of CSS is used and changes you have made may not be reflected.  Force a full refresh of the browser page which *should* reload the full content using `CTRL`+`F5`.